# Create multiple snapshots on Hyper-V 2012 PowerShell all at once

Tags: hyper-v, powershell, windows-server-2012

In the Hyper-V GUI, it is possible to create a collection of snapshots across multiple VMs by selecting multiple VMs, then clicking Snapshot.

In PowerShell on Windows Server 2012, you can request more than one at once by passing the list of VMs as `Checkpoint-VM -VMName @('server1', 'server2')` (for example). But, that does them in series, not in parallel. This matters when you have machines that interact with each other.

Can you only do this by creating snapshots as jobs and letting the asynchronous job start get it very close? Is that was the GUI is doing? Or is there a "proper" way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the GUI in fact run them concurrently or does it run them consecutively? How can you confirm that?

Comment: It's pretty easy to see it's concurrent; you can watch the status column show the progress of multiple requests at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method to do this in Powershell.  It has been discussed in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/311259/how-do-i-make-this-script-run-in-parallel) ServerFault post

Comment: So this is using the asynchronous job approach I mentioned already right? Or is there a nuance I missed?

Comment: Correct.  I don't know that there is a right-way/wrong-way.  Just a way that works for you.

Comment: The better link is the source link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel although as I said this is really just a fancy way of using jobs. I ended up using -AsJob as that is a bit less hassle and gets the same effective result. It's not perfect but it is hopefully close enough.